# ExtJS - How to filter data from a DB based on what I type

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have created an ExtJS (EXtjs4)  app where I have a combo box and populate it with values from the database.

This my code.
First my store:

```
var autoCompleteStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    fields:['onomasia'],
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        url: 'autocomplete/getautocomplete.php',
        method: 'POST'
    }),
baseParams:{task: "onomasia"}      
});
```

The combo box definition:

```
// DEFINE THE COMBO BOX FOR THE AUTOCOMPLETE
var nodeOikismoiField = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
                id:'nodeId',
                fieldLabel: 'Insert NodeId',
                store: autoCompleteStore,
                mode: 'remote',
                displayField: 'onomasia',
                allowBlank: false,
                valueField: 'onomasia',
                anchor:'95%',
                triggerAction: 'all',
                name: 'oikismos',

                labelAlign : 'right',
                width: 200,
                margin: 5,
                minChars:1,
                typeAhead: true, // CHANGES
                typeAheadDelay: 200,// CHANGES
                queryParam: 'query' // CHANGES

});
```

and my PHP script:
**EDITED**

```
<?php
 include 'postgresConnect.php';
 $where = '';
 $queryVar = $_GET['query']; // GET INSTEAD OF POST
 $where = " WHERE komvos LIKE '$queryVar%' ";
 $query = "SELECT komvos FROM oikismoi_covered $where"; 
 $resultImg = pg_query($dbconn, $query);
 $json=array();
 while($oikismos=pg_fetch_row($resultImg)){
     $json[]=array(
                'onomasia'=> $oikismos[0]
    );
}
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

My question is the following:
When I start typing something on the Combo, how can I get only the possible values? For example if I start typing "Ae..." to get only the values starting with these letters.

I realise that I have to change my sql query in the php file and also pass the value in there. 
But what part of code should I change in the ExtJS part?

Comment: send ajax with query select * from table where name like '%yourParam%'

Comment: Can you please give a more detailed example?

Comment: i have the answer something like @Scriptable send

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PHP script you would likely need to do something like this:

```
$where = '';
if (isset($_POST['query'])) {
   $queryVar = $_POST['query'];
   $where = " WHERE `onomasia` LIKE '$queryVar%' "
}

$query = "SELECT onomasia FROM oikismoi_covered $where LIMIT 3";
```

Please bear in mind that this particular query is open to MySql Injection attacks and should be sanitized beforehand, Or use prepared statements with PDO which would be much better.

In your combo definition you should apply the `typeAhead` and `typeAheadDelay` configs

These configs should help:

```
typeAhead: true,
typeAheadDelay: 200,
queryMode: 'remote',
queryParam: 'query' // this is the parameter name passed back to PHP
```

This [link](http://devjs.eu/en/autocomplete-combobox-filter-for-ext-js-4-grid-crud-functionality/) should also help with some more details.

Comment: Thank you. As I wrote in the last part of my question I know how to make the php part. What I don't know is what I have to change in the Extjs code in order to send the parameter.

Comment: And what is: query variable in (isset($_POST['query']). From where do I take this?

Comment: I have updated the answer to include an explanation. You should really check through the available config options on the store and combobox in the documentation

Comment: Thank you. I tried your suggestions and although I don't get any error I still can not filter the data based on the first letters. I get all the values from the database.

Comment: Can you post your updated code in the question above, make sure you add it below as an edit to preserve the original question

Comment: I get a: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'. This is the part where I use the:    if (isset($_POST['query']) {

Comment: I don't understand. Although I see in firebug that the parameter is sent it seems like it doesn't pass in the query!

Comment: there shouldn't be any syntax errors unless you have made a typo. Try var_dump($_REQUEST); in your php code to see what is being sent. You should also be able to see this in the browser console if you use something like firebug for firefox

Comment: there was a missing bracket in the PHP code above, fixed

Comment: There was a missing ";"  in the $where variable. But  still I get the same problem. Data are not filtered based on what I type although the parameter is passed in the ajax request.

Comment: check your http requests in the browser console window

Comment: Thanks for the patience. What I see in the firebug console is a get request . In the params tab I have the "query" attribute with the value I typed on the combo box.

Comment: if its a GET request then $_POST['query'] wont work, try $_GET['query']

Comment: Thank you very much. It works fine now. Although I dont understand why it would work with GET. I have defined in my store a POST method!